# How to enable geo location by default using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, geolocation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing test cases to validate the maps using Selenium webdriver. When I try to open the maps using url then location alert is popped up.

[image]

I want to allow the map to access the current location by default when the map is loaded without location alert.

I have tried using profile in the ChromeOptions but it is not satisfying my requirements.

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> profile = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 1); // 1:allow 2:block
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Certainly not, I dont want to populate popup, website need to use the current geo location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
 googlegeolocationaccess.enabled
```

Please try:

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> profile = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("googlegeolocationaccess.enabled", true);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 1); // 1:allow 2:block
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);
prefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings", 1);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but seems to be not working in incognito mode.

Comment: Is it working in normal mode , ignito mode may not allow it as that's one of the reason to use it

Comment: yes, its working in normal mode

Comment: @light_ray coul you try the updated answer , please upvote and accept the question it helped