# Automation Testing can't bypass location popup

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, automation

I'm doing automation testing and our portal has this new feature that needs to know the location of the user. How can i possibly click the 'Allow' button?
[image: see picture here]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium with Chrome driver you can setup the preferences for the driver to automatically 'Allow' geolocation

[How to enable geo location by default using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65274570/how-to-enable-geo-location-by-default-using-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Try `SendKeys({ESC});` it usually works with this kind of popup.

Comment: Sorry But where does that method exist? or we have to create